# Why is the bottom white in a lucas test?

Tags: reactivity

Consider this positive result from the Lucas test (adding $\ce{ZnCl2/HCl}$ to a tertiary alcohol):
[image]

My question is quite straightforward but I can't find the answer. What is in the top layer (thin and clear) and what is in the bottom milky layer? Also, what is making it milky?

Comment: Do you know your $3^\circ$-alcohol? How much of it you used for the test? Do you used any organic solvent to dissolve it? Your answers might be within answers to those questions.

Comment: The solution might be tertiary alkyl chloride.

Comment: This was not from my experiment - but say 2-methylpropan-2-ol and 3mL?

Comment: Your picture is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_reagent##targetText=Lucas%20test,%E2%86%92%20RCl%20%2B%20H2O). Hence, I 'm strongly suspect this as a homework question.

Comment: Yes it is from wikipedia - why does this mean it's a homework question? I am simply curious what is it that is making it white/cloudy. The picture is for illustration purposes. Even if it WAS a homework question - it still asks for conceptual reasoning which is allowed by the site's policy

Answer (score -1):

I think the bottom layer is the haloalkane, because we're switching the $\ce{OH}$ group of mass $\pu{17 u}$, with chlorine which is $\pu{35.45 u}$. This makes the chloride more dense than the water, which is also formed in the process

$$\ce{ROH + HCl ->[ZnCl2 catalyst] RCl + H2O}$$